# How to add custom fields to Historical Records and assign values to them using signals in django-simple-history

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

[Please check Required Json Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z114.png)
I wanted to add Custom fields to HistoricalRecords with abstract model.I want to display history records with additional field "replaced_with".Each file history should tell by which file it was replaced.

```
models.py:
class AdditionalFileHistory(models.Model):
    replaced_with = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('replaced by')
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ReviewFile(models.Model):
    review = models.OneToOneField(
        Review,
        verbose_name=_('review'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='files'
    )
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('file')
    )
    filename = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('filename')
    )
    
   
    history = HistoricalRecords(bases=[AdditionalFileHistory, ], cascade_delete_history=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Files'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Review Step  {self.file.name}'

signals.py:

@receiver(pre_create_historical_record)
def pre_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    history_instance = kwargs['history_instance']
    source_instance = kwargs['instance']
    history_instance.replaced_with = source_instance.filename
```

it was giving current file history,but we need previous file is replaced by current file in history
something like below:

Comment: You already have the history instance. So, why `history.instance.file` is not enough for you? I didn't get it.

Comment: Here,I need to show like when I replace a file ,file history contains previous file and file by which it got replaced. I attached sample json also.